# Why does Google Oauth restrict apps to use owned domains?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, gmail-api, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an app that uses a sensitive scope (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). Google requires the oauth server to be owned by me. This requirement restricts a huge swath of plug-in's, hosted apps (like amazon lambda or heroku) from using sensitive scopes. IMO, This reduces developer efficiency, reduces app options for users and is an unnecessary overhead since the user is already providing their credentials irrespective of the domain to access the application.

Why does Google Oauth restrict apps to use self-owned domains?

[image: Overly restrictive policy?]

Answer (score -1):

Even if the users are authenticated, the App still needs Authorization. As you can see in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?ref_topic=7440006):

> Verification is the process of proving that you own the property that
>   you claim to own. We need to confirm ownership because once you are
>   verified for a property, you have access to its Google Search data,
>   and can affect its presence on Google Search. Every Search Console
>   property requires at least one verified owner.

You can suggest changes to Google in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Authorization is different than verification. I don't want to be verified because I don't own the above sites. I want them to be authorized to receive Oauth requests.

My question is more around why google restricts authorization to domains I own. I'm trying to understand that requirement as many other services do not do this.